# How to implement an already well implemented module(like stack) in java using a linked list

Tags: java, interface, linked-list, stack

I'm trying to implement an stack using a linked list in Java, But I'm not sure which methods I have to implement(stack is a simple example here), How can I somehow get the methods and then extend my linked list class to implement my own class of stack

I know that somehow I have to use some kind of interface but it would be a great help if someone could guide me here.

Comment: `How to implement an already well implemented module in java` what does it mean even??

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ see the description please!

Comment: See this answer
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552117/implementing-stack-using-linked-lists

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I'm trying to solve an interview question. I have to implement everything my self.I've already created my own linked list, now I'm trying to extend it to create my own stack. But I wasn't sure which methods I have to implement. Now I'm trying to see is there anyway that I overwrite the methods of a Stack that's been implemented already. The good thing about using an already implemented stack is that someone already has found all it's necessary methods. I hope I have answered your question!

Comment: Maybe the jdk interface `java.util.Queue` is a starting point for you to decide which methods you would like to implement.

Comment: You can have a look at the Stack class from the API to see which methods to implement : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: Ali, Something like this ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056784/implementing-a-new-linkedlist-method-in-java and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638289/java-linked-list-search-and-delete-method

Comment: Java doesn't have modules! I suggest you don't ever mention the word module if you want to pass a Java interview.

Answer (score 4):

A stack at its simplest just has `Push()` and `Pop()`. They map directly to the `LinkedList` methods `push` and `pop` already present!

So in order to implement a stack on top of a linked list you need to do....nothing :)